# Pandas Left Join based and if left join condition does not exist, repeat the value of the original into the new joined columns

Tags: python, pandas

If Group contains ' non med' i want to right join on that record and if it does not contain non med I want both values to be the same

```
In
       Volume    Premium           Group
0      5721.0    5057.76          4941.0
1    131778.0  275797.08  4842 (non med)
2   150197.0   165408.2          4842.0
```

```
Out
       Volume_L    Premium_L           Group      Volume_R    Premium_R          
0        5721.0      5057.76          4941.0         5721.0      5057.76
1      150197.0     165408.2          4842.0       131778.0    275797.08
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can split the `df`  in IN  based on the string "non med".

   df_left=df[~df["Group"].astype(str).str.contains("non med")]
   df_right=df[df["Group"].astype(str).str.contains("non med")]
2. Clean up the `Group` column in `df_right` to remove all "non med" string.

   df_right["Group"]=df_right["Group"].astype(str).str.replace("TEXT TO REPLACE HERE","").astype(float)
3. Perform a left join (merge).

   df_final=pd.merge(df_left,df_right,on="Group",suffices=("_L",_R))

   Note: For step 3, ensure that the Group columns in both the df is of same type.
4. Fill data in from Left to right where the data is empty.

   df_final.loc[df["Volume_R"].isnull(),"Volume_R"]=df_final["Volume_L"]
   df_final.loc[df["Premium_R"].isnull(),"Premium_R"]=df_final["Premium_L"]

Comment: its on the same dataframe, _L is the record without Non med in group and _R is the record with non med.

Comment: i used this code and it did not work properly it just joins the record on itself instead of on the non med record

Comment: I get this error based on line 

`  df_right["Group"]=df_right["Group"].astype(str).str.replace(" (non med)","").astype(str)`

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Well try using loc instead then. :)

I am only providing you the basic idea on how to deal with the solution and not the entirety of the code. Do some minor research. 

You can use the code I have written as a skeleton. The code has not been tested but summarizes the basic operations that you can implement to solve the problems you have.